# creating a ivar ( NSMutableString ) works but I get a warning

Tags: objective-c

I have created a simple class called Engine which has an ivar called inputName ( NSMutableString ). Properties have been set ocordingly and all works fine. When I create and instance of Engine called car and set inputName I get the following warning:
**Assigning retained object to unsafe property, object will be released after assignment.**
Apart from the message, car.inputName has been allocated memory and initialized correctly.

When declaring properties (@property NSMutableString *inputName;) I did not assign any attributes. But if I add (strong) I do not get the above warning. How can this be when strong is the default attribute ?? and what would be the best way to give car.inputName a string.

```
#import "Engine.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Engine *car = [[Engine alloc]init];
        car.inputName = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Ford Escot"];
        // yellow warning:Assigning retained object to unsafe property, object will be released after assignment

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Presumably this is an ARC project?

Comment: @trojanfoe - yes - this is a ARC project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strong` is not the default.  [`assign` is the default.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2)

Comment: Thanks Jim. Thats why the error message goes when I add the strong attribute.

Answer (score 2):

__strong is the default for underlying instance variables. If you only declared your instance variable as such (eg, without an accompanying property) and you assign to your ivar directly, it should compile without warning (although you would be ignoring best practice).

When you create a property for accessing an instance variable, the default memory management is assign, which is not safe.

Hence, when you create your property without a strong reference, and then assign to it, the compiler warns you, as it should, that this is unsafe.

Best practice suggests that you only access ivars by property, and that properties express the correct memory management principle for your case. In this case, it would seem to me that your property should be (strong, nonatomic).

```
//h

@interface SomeClass
{
    Engine *__anEngine; // will be __strong
}

@property (nonatomic) Engine *anEngine; //will be assign

//m
Engine *car = [[Engine alloc] init];

__anEngine = car; //retained
self.anEngine = car; //not retained
```